# Perl: how to Capture data displayed by an URL in perl script

Tags: perl

I have a URL which just displays only the SSH key when opened in a browser. 
This URL is an argument to my Perl script. I need to open the HTTP page through Perl and capture the contents of the webpage, i.e the SSH key in a variable and use it further for processing. 
Is there a mechanism to perform this in Perl. I tried to find it online, but no solution fits perfectly!

Comment: Have you tried the `get` function from `LWP::Simple`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 use LWP::Simple;
 $content = get("http://google.com/");
 die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;
```

$content will store everything from the url as the browser sees it so you may have to strip the HTML tags from the content.

See [Link](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/Simple.pm) for more information.

Comment: I tried something called WWW::Mechanize before, but I couldn't get it working. LWP works really good. Thanks for the answer